# xcode6 adding viewController into the navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode6, navigationcontroller

Weird issue here-

Using XCode6, have a navigation controller with my initial view embedded with it.

I am adding another view controller. I added it on the storyboard and all I am trying to do is link this new viewController inside the same navigation controller....(NOT create a new one)

Whenever I ctrl+click the top/menu of the first view controller, it doesn't want to link up to the NEW view controller.

What's going on? It seemed to work like that in xcode4 without issues....

Comment: Are you saying that you can't control-drag from the controller icon (yellow circle with white rectangle inside) to the next controller?

Comment: ahh thank you, I used to be able to just drag the nav menu, I see the icon that you are talking about though- thank you